# How to remove Server Header Azure App Service when requesting with Connect HTTP method

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am facing an issue with Azure App Services, when we request with an HTTP CONNECT method, App Service returns a Bad Gateway Error. Along with the response, it is exposing the Server as well. Is there a way to fix this?

Here is the example

[image: Azure App Service Bad Gateway error]

I am already doing the server header removal in Web.Config and Application_Start method global.asax.

Comment: Could you share you web.config, i tried `requestFiltering` set `removeServerHeader` to true, it could remove the server header.

Comment: I hope you're taking about this

<security>
  <requestFiltering removeServerHeader ="true">
      </requestFiltering>
</security>

It is already set.

Comment: Do you restart you app?

Comment: Yes. I did it after changing the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raised a support issue with Microsoft Azure. This response is not coming from the server, it is handled by their frontend and they can't remove the specific header.