# Security Response header in angular hosted in azure app service

Tags: angular, azure, security, azure-web-app-service

we have pure angular application  ( **not hosted in asp.net mvc core** ) deployed to azure app service.

now requirement is, we need to add few security headers mentioned here

1. https://securityheaders.com/
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security

as well, wanted to remove **X-Powered-By: ASP.NET** header too.

so far on internet or my own search, what i found so far is to add **in webconfig file**, but remember,we have just angular app.

why should i use webconfig for that?

in your experience, how do you handle this situation? or what is the best answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, how did you handled this situation? I have also standalone angular application and I also need to include some security headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This response is not coming from the server, it is handled by their frontend and they can't remove the specific header.

The article you found to add in web.config which is run on IIS. Refer to this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/571).

You can raise a support issue with Microsoft Azure.

Here is a similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61316149/how-to-remove-server-header-azure-app-service-when-requesting-with-connect-http) you could refer to.

Comment: so we're saying, we cannot implement the security headers on stand alone angular application? - https://securityheaders.com/ ?

Comment: You can not remove header in angular app while it is a front end app.

Comment: how about to add more security headers ? i guess, we cannot do add or remove since it is only angular app!

Comment: Yes! You got it.